# PostgreSQL 14 server not running locally on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux, postgresql-14

So yesterday I updated my Ubuntu OS from 20 LTS to 22.04 LTS and installed PostgreSQL from this [source](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/). Running, `psql -V`, I get this:

```
(PostgreSQL) 14.5 (Ubuntu 14.5-1.pgdg22.04+1)
```

Initialized the postgresql with the following:

```
$ service postgresql initdb
$ systemctl enable postgresql
$ systemctl start postgresql
```

When running the `psql` command, I get the following error:

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

Also when running`pg_lsclusters`, I get the following:

```
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner Data directory Log file
```

And when navigating to postgresql directory `ls etc/postgresql/`, it has no files or folders in it.

I also installed `postgresql-contrib`, as mentioned in this [source](https://linuxhint.com/install-and-setup-postgresql-database-ubuntu-22-04/). The reason I looked up this source is that I wanted to initialize the Postgres server, so I followed the commands mentioned in it.

```
$ sudo systemctl start postgresql.service
$ sudo -i -u postgres
postgres@ror:~$ createuser --interactive
Enter name of role to add: juzershakir
Shall the new role be a superuser? (y/n) y
```

Get the following error messages:

```
createuser: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

And when I check the status of the PostgreSQL service:

```
$ sudo systemctl status postgresql.service
postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Fri 2022-09-09 12:58:06 IST; 49min ago
    Process: 10493 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 10493 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 1ms

Sep 09 12:58:06 ror systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Sep 09 12:58:06 ror systemd[1]: Finished PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

I am no expert in this, but from this error message, it seems like the service starts and then closes. Why would this be the case? What steps have I missed?

---

Online sources I have already referred to:

- [PostgreSQL: Why psql can't connect to server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31645550/postgresql-why-psql-cant-connect-to-server)
- [Psql could not connect to server: No such file or directory, 5432 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42653690/psql-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory-5432-error)
- [could not connect to server: "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22762635/could-not-connect-to-server-var-run-postgresql-s-pgsql-5432)
- [psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69754628/psql-error-connection-to-server-on-socket-tmp-s-pgsql-5432-failed-no-such)

Commands I have tried:

```
$ sudo ln -s /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

```
$ sudo service postgresql start --force
```

```
$ cat /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432                                                                                                                                   
cat: /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432: No such file or directory
```

```
$cd /tmp
l
   rwxrwxrwt   25   root       root         24 KiB   Fri Sep  9 13:58:14 2022    ./
   rwxr-xr-x   20   root       root          4 KiB   Wed Dec 22 11:15:40 2021    ../
   rwx------    2   jsubuntu   jsubuntu      4 KiB   Fri Sep  9 12:32:07 2022    .com.google.Chrome.o8bjs4/
   rwxrwxrwt    2   root       root          4 KiB   Fri Sep  9 12:29:41 2022    .font-unix/
   rwxrwxrwt    2   root       root          4 KiB   Fri Sep  9 12:30:15 2022    .ICE-unix/
   rwx------    3   root       root          4 KiB   Fri Sep  9 12:30:14 2022    snap.canonical-livepatch/
   rwx------    3   root       root          4 KiB   Fri Sep  9 12:30:15 2022    snap.snapd-desktop-integration/
   rwx------    3   root       root          4 KiB   Fri Sep  9 12:30:16 2022    snap.snap-store/
   rwx------    3   root       root          4 KiB   Fri Sep  9 12:30:13 2022    systemd-private-64f08d0504e04acfb3259292fa13580c-apache2.service-ZrAICM/
   rwx------    3   root       root          4 KiB   Fri Sep  9 12:30:14 2022    systemd-private-64f08d0504e04acfb3259292fa13580c-bluetooth.service-tGJABQ/
   rwx------    3   root       root          4 KiB   Fri Sep  9 12:30:17 2022    systemd-private-64f08d0504e04acfb3259292fa13580c-colord.service-En9sFA/
   rwx------    3   root       root          4 KiB   Fri Sep  9 12:30:18 2022    systemd-private-64f08d0504e04acfb3259292fa13580c-fwupd.service-okItPb/
   rwx------    3   root       root          4 KiB   Fri Sep  9 12:30:13 2022    systemd-private-64f08d0504e04acfb3259292fa13580c-ModemManager.service-KbJJ4J/
   rwx------    3   root       root          4 KiB   Fri Sep  9 12:30:13 2022    systemd-private-64f08d0504e04acfb3259292fa13580c-power-profiles-daemon.service-nguChr/
   rwx------    3   root       root          4 KiB   Fri Sep  9 12:30:13 2022    systemd-private-64f08d0504e04acfb3259292fa13580c-redis-server.service-EaKdzC/
   rwx------    3   root       root          4 KiB   Fri Sep  9 12:30:13 2022    systemd-private-64f08d0504e04acfb3259292fa13580c-switcheroo-control.service-hLF6lp/
   rwx------    3   root       root          4 KiB   Fri Sep  9 12:30:13 2022    systemd-private-64f08d0504e04acfb3259292fa13580c-systemd-logind.service-jMNsHm/
   rwx------    3   root       root          4 KiB   Fri Sep  9 12:29:41 2022    systemd-private-64f08d0504e04acfb3259292fa13580c-systemd-oomd.service-ZtaPW4/
   rwx------    3   root       root          4 KiB   Fri Sep  9 12:29:41 2022    systemd-private-64f08d0504e04acfb3259292fa13580c-systemd-resolved.service-gHZzR9/
   rwx------    3   root       root          4 KiB   Fri Sep  9 12:29:41 2022    systemd-private-64f08d0504e04acfb3259292fa13580c-systemd-timesyncd.service-Ycbvmk/
   rwx------    3   root       root          4 KiB   Fri Sep  9 12:30:16 2022    systemd-private-64f08d0504e04acfb3259292fa13580c-upower.service-PBPl2C/
   rwxrwxrwt    2   root       root          4 KiB   Fri Sep  9 12:29:41 2022    .Test-unix/
   rwx------    2   jsubuntu   jsubuntu      4 KiB   Fri Sep  9 12:30:18 2022    tracker-extract-3-files.1000/
   rwxrwxrwt    2   root       root          4 KiB   Fri Sep  9 12:30:15 2022    .X11-unix/
   rwxrwxrwt    2   root       root          4 KiB   Fri Sep  9 12:29:41 2022    .XIM-unix/
   r--r--r--    1   jsubuntu   jsubuntu     11 B     Fri Sep  9 12:30:15 2022    .X0-lock 
   r--r--r--    1   jsubuntu   jsubuntu     11 B     Fri Sep  9 12:30:15 2022    .X1-lock
```

```
$ sudo nano /etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_ident.conf
(Directory doesnt exist)
```

Comment: After installation, did you run initdb ? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/runtime.html

Comment: Yes indeed! I will update the post for these commands.

Comment: And did initdb create the database cluster?

Comment: I ran pg_lsclusters command and it returned the same output as mentioned in the post. So, no it didn't create a cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `service postgresql initdb` doesn't create any clusters (which was true in my case) then create a database cluster, like:

```bash
sudo pg_createcluster --start (pg_version) (cluster_name)
```

For ex:

```bash
sudo pg_createcluster --start 14 mycluster
```

To list out all available clusters:

```bash
Ver Cluster   Port Status Owner    Data directory                   Log file
14  mycluster 5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/14/mycluster /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-14-mycluster.log
```

As we can see the **cluster is now successfully created** and when I navigate to `ls /etc/postgresql/`, a folder named `14` is created which corresponds to the version of PostgreSQL's cluster we initiated.
Navigating to directory `14` will return the directory whose name corresponds to the cluster name we gave when we initiated the cluster. Hence my directory looks something like this:

```bash
$ ls /etc/postgresql/14/mycluster
   conf.d/       environment        pg_ctl.conf        pg_hba.conf        pg_ident.conf        postgresql.conf        start.conf
```

---

**Creating new role/user**:
Since I have just installed pg in my system, I don't have any roles available. So I will need to create one via `postgres` account which is automatically created when we install PostgreSQL.

```bash
$ sudo -i -u postgres                                                                                                                                                     
postgres@ror:~$ createuser --interactive
Enter name of role to add: jsubuntu
Shall the new role be a superuser? (y/n) y
```

The user has now been created as a superuser. Now we need to set the password for it. We can do that by logging in as a `postgres` super user

```bash
$ sudo su postgres
```

Open PostgreSQL Interactive terminal by: `psql`:

```
postgres@ror:/etc/postgresql/14/mycluster$ psql
```

Lists all the pg users:

```
postgres=# \du
```

Now to change the password of an existing user in my case its `jsubuntu`, I will run the following:

```
ALTER USER jsubuntu WITH PASSWORD 'password';
```

If you get an output of `ALTER ROLE` then the password has been successfully set.

Now let's quit the session with `exit` command.

So till now, we have successfully created a cluster and a PostgreSQL user which I will use to create databases.

---

Now when I run `psql` command it shows me a different error:

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  database "jsubuntu" does not exist
```

Let's see the pg log file:

```bash
sudo nano /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-14-mycluster.log
```

In this file, I see the following error showing up:

```bash
2022-09-09 18:49:41.497 IST [15498] jsubuntu@jsubuntu FATAL:  database "jsubuntu" does not exist
```

Understanding this error message, the part `jsubuntu@jsubuntu` tells that the user `jsubuntu` should have a database named `jsubuntu`.
Initially, I didn't think this was true but when other tricks didn't work I created a database with the same name and was successfully able to establish a  connection.

```
$ psql
psql (14.5 (Ubuntu 14.5-1.pgdg22.04+1))
Type "help" for help.

jsubuntu=#
```

The name of the psql also changed from `postgres` to `jsubuntu`.

---

**References:**

- [Cannot connect to PostgreSQL server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/389459/cannot-connect-to-postgresql-server?rq=1)